# Почему __android_log_print() не пишет в лог?

Tags: c, android, android-ndk

Мое приложение успешно компилируется но __android_log_print() не пишет в лог хотя __android_log_write() работает.
В чем может быть причина, почему __android_log_print() не работает?

Comment: Какие аргументы передаёте в метод? Код использования покажите. Какая IDE?

Comment: __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "qqq", "tratata") - Не работает __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO , "qqq", "tratata") - Работает.
Юзаю ndk build.

Comment: LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog же подключён?